# SQL get the latest records from a set of data

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table of holdings where each holding has a date column. e.g.

```
id   |   holding_name   |   value   |   holding_date
----------------------------------------------------
1    |   iShares MSCI   |   2032    |   2013-12-31
2    |   Vanguard Bonds |   5332    |   2013-12-31
3    |   iShares MSCI   |   2241    |   2014-01-31
4    |   Vanguard Bonds |   6236    |   2014-01-31
```

If I wanted to select only the latest holdings I could go

```
SELECT * FROM holdings WHERE holdings.holding_date = '2014-01-31'
```

But what if I don't know that the latest date is 2014-01-31? Is there a way to build this into the query?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to show no research effort.

Comment: I'm not sure how that makes it off-topic. I admit I could have dug deeper in the research but I was unsure of what to search for. It never deviates from its topic however

Comment: So how much can your [table of holding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_holding) hold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM holdings
WHERE holding_date = (SELECT MAX(holding_date) from holdings)
```

Comment: It's unclear if `holding_date` is a `varchar` or a `datetime` field here. It looks like potentially a `varchar`...

Comment: Doesn't matter. In this format, they sort the same either way.

Comment: True, with year first. Why not just `ORDER BY holding_date DESC` and `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: holding_date is a date, not a varchar

Comment: @crush . . . Because that will return only one row and there might be multiple at the maximum date.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't get that from the question initially, but seems evident now. Glad I didn't answer too quickly, hah.

Comment: Barmar that seems to work, thanks. @crush because I want more than one result - there are several records per date.